# Replace Number in Row with Description When Running SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I've got two tables: one with customer data, one with location data.

**`TABLE1`** has four fields: `USERNAME` , `FIRST_NAME` , `LAST_NAME` and `REGION`. The data that can come back from that `REGION` field can be either `'1'` or `'2'`.

**`TABLE2`** is basically acting as a "definition" table. Within, there are two fields `REGION_ID` and `REGION_DESC`.

A SELECT query on the first row of **`TABLE 2`** might look like this:

```
    REGION_ID | REGION_DESC
    -----------------------
    1         | Eastern
```

When running my select query, I'd like to be able to pull, for example, `USERNAME` and then `REGION_ID` as "Region" and then have the `'1'` or `'2'` automatically be replaced with its respective definition; "Western" or "Eastern."

So, instead of this:

```
    USERNAME | REGION
    -------------------
    1        | 1
```

I'd see this:

```
    USERNAME | REGION
    ------------------------
    jasonh   | Eastern
```

I'm sure I've seen this before I but I can't seem to find what this is called... and, for whatever reason, I'm apparently unable to find the appropriate verbiage because my Google searches because I just can't find that for which I'm looking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you `TABLE1` has an ID for the `USERNAME` column, then I think your leaving out a 3rd table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to JOIN the two tables together based on the common region ID that they both share in common.

```
SELECT t1.USERNAME, t2.REGION_DESC
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.REGION = t2.REGION_ID;
```

Comment: I guess you mean `ON t1.REGION = t2.REGION_ID` ?

Comment: @MatthewPK: Thanks for helping my fat fingers! :-)

Comment: Was that all it was? Oy. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much you guys.